# Recursively reverse an array starting from index 0

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to recursively reverse an array passing only 2 parameters, but seems not working. that's what i've tried

```
private static void rotate(char[]a, int i){
    if(i==a.length){
        return;
    }else{
        char temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
        a[a.length - 1 - i] = temp;
        rotate(a, i+1);         
    }   
}
```

if i pass something like char[] x = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
it will print cbc instead of cba.
what's wrong?

Comment: You could print out each recursion step (array contents) and get an idea what happens. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have incorrect recursion exit condition. The correct one is
`if (i == a.length/2) {
    return;
 }`

You swap elements with corresponding element from the end of array. When you reach the middle of array - all work is done.